# Is it safe to restore preferences right after apply() is called from SharedPreferences.Editor?

Tags: android, concurrency, sharedpreferences

I'm having problems to decide if I should use `apply()` or `commit()` from [SharedPreferences.Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)
Since `apply()` is async, and we are going to read right after write, it's safer to use `commit()`. On the other hand, this method might block the UI thread for far too long. I don't want to use local variables because I want to read other settings, and since I don't know where `sendData()` will be called, the mix of reading through setting and local variables will add unnecessary complexity.

```
  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Apply the edits!
  editor.apply();

  // Read data of SharedPreferences (including other previously data)
  // and send to web service
  sendData();
```

Above is a code snippet of something similar I want to do. I want to make sure that when I read any data from SharedPreferences, all settings were committed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you dont know and when does `sendData()` will be called then you have no choice but to use `commit` instead of `apply` that it will give you the previously added data when you read and send it to the external server, but apply wont if it is still putting the data to the disk but you already read the data which will give you inconsistent result that it is executed asynchronously.

There is one way to know that data is stored, through using listener `registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in the `SharedPreferences` this will only work if you always know the last added data to the disk before you read it.